# Trying to understand the scope of the ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

The `ConcurrentHashMap` provides thread-safe but the docs state:

> " However, even though all operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do not entail locking"

So from this I understand that getting or setting a key and value are thread-safe, but modifying the actual VALUE of any given key isn't (by value I actaully mean the value or state of that object).

I'm just confused on how this works, at the moment I think things work like this.

The `ConcurrentHashMap` only gaurantees the key's are thread-safe in terms setting/getting them.  But the object you put inside the map has to gaurd for concurrency by itself.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But the object you put inside the map has to gaurd for concurrency by itself.

Your understanding is correct.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> However, even though all operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do not entail locking, and there is not any support for locking the entire table in a way that prevents all access.

What the above is also saying is that there is no built-in mechanism for automatic locking of the hash map while the reading takes place. In particular, this means that `get()` operations can overlap with concurrent modifications performed by other threads.

The document goes on to explain the concurrency semantics:

> Retrieval operations (including `get`) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including `put` and `remove`). Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset. For aggregate operations such as `putAll` and `clear`, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only some entries. Similarly, `Iterators` and `Enumerations` return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration.

Comment: So looping and persisting data to a db might not get all the keys then right? how would you do that, locking the entire map I guess right?

Comment: The ConcurrentHashMap doesn't have a global locking feature. You'd have to lock externally, which sort-of defeats the idea of efficiently filling it from multiple threads because the dump-to-db lock would need to be checked.

Comment: When you iterate on the entries of a `ConcurrentHashMap`, "the iterator is a "weakly consistent" iterator that will never throw `ConcurrentModificationException`, and guarantees to traverse elements as they existed upon construction of the iterator, and may (but is not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction."  That's probably the best you can get.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, how could the "weakly consistent" part be implemented. Any thing like: (1) Iterator is created --> a copy of the map (readonly) is created and made available to iterator.  (2) elements are added/removed from orginal map. (3) Later, at some point in time, change-in-state to the orginal map is detected (detected by whom... saying simply JVM will be too broad) and so any iterators created earlier are supplied with a new copy of the map.       So is this fictitious or reality.

Comment: @samshers, a reference to the then-current guts of the map is passed to the iterator upon creation.  Some changes may be reflected in that, or the map may e.g. get resized, in which case those guts are replaced in the map, but the iterator is _not_ updated.  That makes the iterator weakly consistent: it may reflect changes to the map, or it may not.  There is no copying, and no change detection from the iterator; the iterator just reflects the state of the reference it got when the map was created.

Answer (score 2):

What you say is true by default -- there would be no way for the map to enforce the thread safety of either its keys or its values since these are objects that come from outside. What you read about the retrieval of objects, however, has nothing to do with that fact. The map doesn't block while retrieving a value so another update may be happening at the same time (these operation can overlap).

Comment: Ok so it is sort of 'eventually consistant', meaning you may be reading stale daya?

Comment: If you iterate over it, then yes. An atomic operation like `get` will not read data that was stale upon the onset of that `get`. It may be stale by the time you observe the return value, of course. The point of using a concurrent structure like this is not that you don't ever block, but that you block only when absolutely necessary. If you need to iterate over the map as it appears at a certain point, you'll have to block.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik,  could you elaborate on how the eventual/week consistency part of this map works

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea of the ConcurrentHashMap is that only modifications use a lock, while retrieval-only operations don't. This is possible because the entire data structure and the operations on it are defined in a way that allows `get()` to only ever see a "consistent enough" state of the map to do its work. If there's currently an insert operation in progress, then `get()` either sees the result or it doesn't, but it won't ever see a partial result or even temporarily invalid data.